# SQL DELETE with 2 Joins?

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have to delete a table, which has disabled users in it. The problem is, that I have to use the where clause in the end. This is the most important point, cause otherwise i can't test my query.

The where clause is important, cause without it I would delete the whole database, not only the disabled users.

```
DELETE a
   FROM CONTENT_PERM a
   JOIN user_mapping b
     ON a.USERNAME = b.USER_KEY
        (JOIN CWD_USER c
           ON b.USERNAME = c.USER_NAME)
  WHERE c.ACTIVE = 'F';
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?  Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: I`m using the SQL developer. The error is that the first where clause isn´t right

Comment: SQL developer is a tool, not a database.  Which _database_ are you using?

Comment: The database is confluence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below

```
DELETE FROM CONTENT_PERM
WHERE USERNAME IN (SELECT USER_KEY FROM user_mapping WHERE USERNAME IN (SELECT USER_NAME
from CWD_USER where ACTIVE = 'F'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you don't need `()` in between for JOIN

```
DELETE a
FROM CONTENT_PERM a
JOIN user_mapping b
ON a.USERNAME = b.USER_KEY
JOIN CWD_USER c
ON b.USERNAME = c.USER_NAME
WHERE c.ACTIVE = 'F';
```

Comment: There is a syntax error with the first FROM - i think I have to change my query but I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Just use Select Query by just removing Delete and check whether you are getting proper result and then based on the result you can take action to delete query.
like as follows.

```
Select a
FROM CONTENT_PERM a
JOIN user_mapping b
ON a.USERNAME = b.USER_KEY
JOIN CWD_USER c
ON b.USERNAME = c.USER_NAME
WHERE c.ACTIVE = 'F';
```